# How to change GK-coordinates to UTM with the field calculator in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, utm

i have  a qgis project in ETRS89 (UTM) with some vectorshapes. i already transformes them from GK into UTM. but now the attribute table still show me the GK-coordinates. HOW can i change it? with the field calculator?!

Please help me :)
Lena

Answer (score 2):

The data in the attribute table will not change when you reproject the geometries.

After reprojection, you have to add new columns with `$x` and `$y` values. These will be in the coordiante system at the moment when you add them. You can delete the old columns with coordinates if they are not useful to you anymore.

Comment: Yes i know that the attribute table wont change after reprojeting.

Comment: Sorry, i pressed enter to early. What i mean is, e.g. i have GK : 3472026/ 5895225 and want them to UTM- coordinates :471961 / 5893308. With $x and $ y i just get the lat/long. or am i wrong? thanks for your help !!

Comment: You get the coordinates in the CRS that is current at the time of editing. So if you reproject to UTM, you get UTM coordinates.